# Python Pandas: Merging one column to another data frame does not return the same number of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames: first data frame (let say df1) has 389 rows with 5 columns, the second data frame (let say df2) has 10025 rows with 10 columns. I want to merge one of the columns (let say column name is 'description') to the first data frame. I was using pd.merge() command to merge column like below:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2[['ID','description']],on='ID',how='left')
```

However, above command returns 22338 rows. When I searched on stackoverflow, I found one thread where it was asking to use the drop_duplicates with the second dataframe. So I changed my code like below:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2[['ID','description']].drop_duplicates(),on='ID',how='left')
```

When I ran the above command it returned 751 rows. So still I am not getting the desired number of rows i.e. 389. Could anyone guide me how to fix the issue?

Comment: Check for duplicate values for `ID` column in `df1` itself. Or, duplicate `ID` values in df2. Either of the case will be there.

Comment: it would be nice if you could post a sample of df1 and df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have either a "[many-to-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model))" or "[many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))" relationship. To eliminate this, you can do the following:

```
pd.merge(
    df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']),
    df2[['ID','description']].drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']),
    on='ID',
    how='left'
)
```